# Make the type of a field conditionally based on another field type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make a field optional when the other field is of type X?

I want `action.meta` to be `never` when the `payload` is an array, and when it's an `object` make it `{ resourceId: string }`

```
const ADD_RESOURCES = 'ADD_RESOURCES'

type Resource = { id: string }

type AddResource<R = any> = {
  type: typeof ADD_RESOURCES
  payload: R extends [] ? Resource[] : (Resource | null)
  meta: R extends [] ? never : { // when payload is an array, make meta never
    resourceId: string
  }
}

const action: Resource = {
  type: ADD_RESOURCES,
  payload: [{ id: '1' }]
  // allow me to omit meta when the payload is array
}

if (Array.isArray(action.payload)) {
  action.meta // make action.meta never
} else {
  action.meta // make action.meta { resourceId: string }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a union in this case. Since you discriminate by the `payload` property being an array or not, you can't really use the discriminated union pattern to narrow `action` and you will need to use a custom type guard:

```
const ADD_RESOURCES = 'ADD_RESOURCES'

type Resource = { id: string }

type AddResource = {
    type: typeof ADD_RESOURCES
    payload: Resource | null,
    meta: { // when payload is an array, make meta never
        resourceId: string
    }
} | {
    type: typeof ADD_RESOURCES
    payload: Resource[],
    meta: never // you can just omit this.. or type it as undefined 
}

const action: AddResource = {
  type: ADD_RESOURCES,
  payload: [{ id: '1' }]
} as AddResource // Assertion here so flow analasys doesn't just use the actual type of the object literal instead of AddResource

function isArrayResource(r: AddResource): r is Extract<AddResource, { payload: Resource[] }> {
    return Array.isArray(action.payload);
}

if (isArrayResource(action)) {
  action.meta // action.meta never
} else {
  action.meta //  action.meta { resourceId: string }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggEQQfQEoFEDKB5AqqgYSxgF4YByRFDHfIzcgKEagE8AHAUxlU4hACuAJ2DcyAbxgBLACYAuGNCFSwAcxgBfZmy7wZM3v2GjSMcYxiWYOzgpsgAZvCRoseQlgtX2AQ1YAbEB95Hj5BEW4AHxgwAX9-ABovSwBbTigfBUkAemyYAHcAC04wGF8AoJlpCBgfUp8hIT8EmBSfAGtuNIyYzgA3TiFkq0shMONOAEkQpRVVYa0NGGjzEZs7Dk5HZ2o3Ok8R8sDghUNw0QBtAF0kke7M3oGhGFyYVkEYYDqYACsBaBgIBSUlgUEKUggADpIYDnjZpLAfDUBGAZJwHCpOFVGFpGKBIIjgFApOAFHB9GcJqZVtZNmSXDR3PRbmU-McQhdJLIFOQAIzkTRXHG1GrkgzjCIvPJwCAQQbE8AwYpjRQgGAOQL5WpgHz+JGsGoyEB8MDkWB-AH-bhg7g+IkCXW03TbG2AgBGP04RJg-hBg0dKmgnGCgKcYspEWYDhRRJJpQhcEafgjogAFEIyRSJaIAJQKZ4QmDoAAeUCaRIAPOHs5wWpIjpVTjXrpoAHxmYZjKDCUqJpqsSEJpOsVN2hVgSEN4I5gDcOOYUicqaH-ZTnFHsfAOZzHcsY7jkPuUtqm4nR7A-UGws4-jlu5P48P6R8x4fB6PkjGRgi0wUszUmg4kAA)